# How to delete all Images with specific sizes from a Woocommerce product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have copied products via a macro from another website, but it copied by mistake the thumbnails as well. Now all my products have thumbnails also attached as product gallery images. It is hectic for me the size of the images are same 112 x 112.

Is there anyway to delete all the images of 112 x 112 from my product gallery images?

Comment: I think following [these trivial rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) could make your posts much better with only a little work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://wpsites.net/web-design/remove-woocommerce-single-thumbnail-images-from-product-details-page/) you can delete any image from woocommerce.

***Example code***:

```
// Remove product thumbnail from the cart page 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_empty_string' );
```

or

```
// Remove product images from the shop loop 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

Comment: i dont want to delete all the thumbnails or product images, i want to delete the thumbnails / product images only which have the size of 112 x 112 pixels.